# Google Appengine application written in Java with access to Python+Numpy+Scipy?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, numpy, scipy

I have a rather big appengine application completely written in Java. I would need to obtain results from functions completely written in python (if possible 3.x) with numpy and similar packages.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking in two options.

1. You can write an app-engine's python module (now called [services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#services_the_building_blocks_of_app_engine)) using default or [Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). Then your default module have access to this special module via HTTP requests, synchronously via [URL Fetch API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/outbound-requests) or async via [Push Queue API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/), which can only be done via *.appspot.com URLs.
   [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Communication_between_modules) is the official docs about module communication uses ModuleService API which resolves module addresses to *.appspot.com addresses.
2. You can try to execute python code using PythonInterpreter class, but i not sure if the sandbox avoid to use it.

Comment: Thank you; the Flexible Environment looks very promising; I can even use docker and have custom environment! I will go into details!